# Regular expression in php to search url with a given pattern

Tags: php, regex

I want to search a given text for local URLs in link's *href* attributes, using regular expression. Currently, I have this regular expression:

```
'/href=["\']?([^"\'>]+)["\']?/'
```

Now, I'd like to add some more filtering: Only get those links, which start like this:

```
XXXX-XX-XX
```

Where `X` is a number. This should match this: **2015-05-15/**, **2015-05-15_03_21_32/** and also **2014-12-21** (any date set by me).

Comment: `'/href=["\']?\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[^"\'>]+)\b["\']?/'`

Comment: This unfortunately does not match this format: **2015-05-15_03_21_32/**.

Comment: remove the last `\b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
href=["']?(\d{4}(?:[-_]\d{2})+)["']?
```

PHP: `$re = "#href=[\"']?(\d{4}(?:[-_]\d{2})+)[\"']?#";`

Explanation:

- `href=["']?` - matches `href=` and an optional single or double quote
- `(\d{4}(?:[-_]\d{2})+)` - a capturing group around the `href` attribute value

  - `\d{4}` - Exactly 4 digits
  - `(?:[-_]\d{2})+` - 1 or more groups of `-`/`_` + 2-digit numbers
- `["']?` - matches an optional single or double quote

See [Regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/nT1cD6/1) and [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/7kVdSN)

Comment: Great, I also added an explanation, so that in case you need to modify it, you will know where :)

Comment: @Zoli: You limited the month to April or May and year to 2014 or 2015. Basically, your updated regex can be contracted to `href=["']?201[45]-0[45]((?:[-_]\d{2})+)["']?`. Please see [my update with added sample texts](https://regex101.com/r/yH0pJ5/4).

Comment: Why this: https://regex101.com/r/yH0pJ5/5 does not match anything in php and it does here?

Comment: Could you post the exact regex declaration you have in your PHP code?

Comment: it is the same as here. **$regex = 'href=["\']?(201[45]-0[45](?:[-_]\d{2})+)["\']?';**

Comment: That is the point. You need to declare it with delimiters, e.g. `$regex = '#href=["\']?(201[45]-0[45](?:[-_]\d{2})+)["\']?#';`. Also, after that you can get all the captured substrings using `preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);  print_r($matches[1]);`. Or, to access all data, `print_r($matches);`.

Comment: It works, I had **preg_match** instead of **preg_match_all** :)